# Allow passwordless root login on the serial console

Tags: centos, rhel, authentication, serial-console

I do a lot of local development work with (CentOS/RHEL) virtual machines. Rather than configuring everything with a default root password -- which, if exposed to the network, can be problematic -- I'd like to configure them to allow passwordless root login only on the serial console.

My first attempt was to simply replace the default `ExecStart` command for  `serial-getty@.service` with a command line using the `--autologin` option:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 --noclear --autologin root ttyS0 $TERM
```

While this skips the `login:` prompt, it still prompts for a root password. This appears to be a limitation of the `login` program under Linux.

I also tried replacing the default login program with a shell, like this:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 --noclear -n -l /bin/bash ttyS0 $TERM
```

But this runs afoul of selinux: while I get a `bash` shell, it has no access to anything:

```
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
# ls /etc/systemd
ls: cannot open directory '/etc/systemd': Permission denied
```

Elsewhere on the net, people have suggested just removing the password hash from `/etc/{password,shadow}`, but of course that results in a different set of problems: now any user can `su -` without a password.

Any thoughts on how to make this work properly?

Comment: It should be possible to use PAM for what you want. But is there any reason why you don't want to set up password-less ssh login to root?

Comment: I already have passwordless ssh login available, but if the network configuration is unknown a priori or fails to come up for some reason, serial console access is tremendously convenient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some experimenting, I've got something that works:

1. Run `systemctl edit serial-getty@ttyS0.service`, and add the following:

   ```
   [Service]
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 --noclear --autologin root ttyS0 $TERM
   ```

   This will cause `agetty` to auto-login the `root` user, but with only this change the system will still prompt you for the root password.
2. We can configure `/etc/pam.d/login` to authenticate `root` logins on the console without a password.  Add the following to the top of `/etc/pam.d/login`:

   ```
   auth sufficient pam_listfile.so item=tty sense=allow file=/etc/securetty onerr=fail apply=root
   ```

   This will cause the PAM stack to check for the login tty in `/etc/securetty`, and to skip other authentication mechanisms if it finds it.
3. Add the serial port to `/etc/securetty`:

   ```
   # echo ttyS0 > /etc/securetty
   ```

With these changes in place, you'll see the following on the serial console when you boot:

```
CentOS Linux 8 (Core)
Kernel 4.18.0-80.11.2.el8_0.x86_64 on an x86_64

localhost login: root (automatic login)

Last login: Sun Nov 17 00:29:36 on ttyS0
[root@localhost ~]#
```

...and if you log out, you'll end up right back at the shell prompt.

Note that I've used the filename `/etc/securetty` here, which in days of yore actually did something else (it controlled terminals on which `root` was allowed to log in). So if that bothers you, use a different file :).

Comment: "This will cause agetty to auto-login the root user, but with only this change the system will still prompt you for the root password." This is a contradictory sentence.

Comment: @user189395 in fact is is not! But I can see why you might read it that way at first glance. I'm open to alternative phrasings.

Comment: Doesn't "auto-login" mean you don't need to enter a password?

Comment: In this case, it means it behaves as if you had typed `root` the `login:` prompt: it automatically initiates a root login, but still prompts you for a password. Maybe that's a better way of putting it?

Comment: I wonder, would it be also possible to use [`pam_securetty.so`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_securetty)?

Comment: This appears to work as well:
`auth sufficient pam_securetty.so`
But take it with a grain of salt, I'm a beginner when it comes to _pam_.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why I didn't mention `pam_securetty` when I wrote this :). Thanks for the comments.