# How do I configure passwordless serial console access on CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, getty

This [official Red Hat page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/index) offers some vague hints.

> Since /etc/securetty listed many possible devices so that the
>   practical effect in most cases was to allow by default, this change
>   has only a minor impact.  However, if you use a more restrictive
>   configuration, you need to add a line enabling the pam_securetty.so
>   module to the appropriate files in the /etc/pam.d directory, and
>   create a new /etc/securetty file.

It seems odd there is no cleaner way of allowing passwordless serial console access.

This [page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552576/allow-passwordless-root-login-on-the-serial-console) provides a solution that works well enough but I can't help wondering if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current state of CentOS 8, I don't think so.

The problem is that a traditional Unix login from a serial port involves two components: a `getty` process to initialize the port settings and prompt for the username, and a `login` process to prompt for a password, check it and initiate the user's session. The RHEL/CentOS SELinux rules have been written with this in mind.

You could make it simpler to configure automatic logins by replacing the combination of `agetty` and `login` by something else that does both jobs, and adjusting the PAM and SELinux configurations to match, but you'll find that to be far more complex than the three simple steps listed [in the link you provided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552576/allow-passwordless-root-login-on-the-serial-console).

Configuring an automatic login is a pretty significant action in terms of security, so it generally should be a multi-step procedure so it'll be unlikely to be done by accident. And if you find yourself doing it often, there's nothing to stop you from automating it using a tool of your choice (e.g. just a script, or perhaps something like Ansible).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar concern about lack of cleaner approach so I had to come up with a different solution than provided in the linked question.

1. You need to configure console for the kernel. It depends on the platform but typically it's `console=ttyS0` or `console=hvc0`. Then you don't need to append serial console to `/etc/securetty`, as mentioned in [pam_securetty(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man8/pam_securetty.8.html):

> ```
>    pam_securetty [...] will also allow root logins on the tty specified
>    with console= switch on the kernel command line and on ttys from the
>    /sys/class/tty/console/active.
> ```

2. root login should be explicitly [allowed](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/PAM_Configuration_Files#ex.pam-config) on the serial console, i.e. `/etc/pam.d/login` should have `pam_securetty` module:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth        required    pam_securetty.so
...
```

3. Then you need to configure autologin in the systemd [getty](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html), run `systemctl edit serial-getty@ttyS0.service` and replace parameters passed to [login](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man1/login.1.html) `-o '-p -- \\u'` with autologin:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin root --noclear --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM
```